# Sublime Text 3 and Anaconda distribution (not plugin) issue

Tags: linux, path, sublime-text-3

I've been using Anaconda distribution(for NumPy,Pandas library). Recently I've tried to use Sublime Text 3. Problem is Sublime text cannot use my Anaconda installation. It is using the default python installation.

During Anaconda's installation, I've tried set it as global/default python setup and later also added anaconda/bin to my $PATH.

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/qfarhan/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

$ echo $PYTHONPATH 
/home/qfarhan/anaconda/bin:

$ which python
/home/qfarhan/anaconda/bin/python
```

But for

```
import request
import pandas as pd
```

gives the error

```
import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

Immediately after the error it prints a path line:

```
[path: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games]
```

Which does not contain the anaconda directory. So Sublime text 3 is using a different PATH than mine. Can someone help me to resolve this issue?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Running the sublime text using the same shell where $PATH points to Anaconda solves the issue, though the different $PATH variable issue remains unresolved.